# Аналог аннотации, задающей Url запроса в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, spring-mvc, чпу

Одна из "крутых фич" в Spring MVC - это то, что перед методом контроллера можно указать специально аннотацию, которая будет задавать Url обрабатываемого запроса. Таким образом очень легко сделать ЧПУ.

Вопрос: а можно ли точно также поступить с ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: "Крутые фичи" в Spring MVC - это те которые лично я считаю полезными. Может кто-то их тоже считает полезными.

Comment: гугл достаточно много информации выдаёт по запросу  [asp.net чпу](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=asp.net+%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83), например, [ЧПУ (красивый урл) в ASP.NET. Routing Webforms.](http://blog.webferia.ru/web/asp-net/routing-url-rewriting/)

Comment: хотелось бы как Spring MVC - что-типа этого